# $y=x^2-x^3$ Area under curve

Tags: limits, summation

I have to use the limit process to fund the area of the region between the graph of the function, and the x-axis over the given interval.

$f(x)=x^2-x^3$ in the interval of $[-1,0]$

I started the problem by solving for $\Delta x$, and got that $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$.  Then I got $c_i=a+i\Delta x$, and got $c_i=-1+\frac{i}{n}$

Then I plugged it into the limit process:

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(f(c_i)\Delta x)$

Long Story short I got $1$ to be my answer is it correct? If not then how do I get the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the area under the curve, evaluate:

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(f(c_i)\Delta x)$

$\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{0 - (-1)}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$

$c_i = a + i\Delta x = -1 + \frac{i}{n}$

$f(c_i) = (c_i)^2 - (c_i)^3 = \frac{4i^2}{n^2} - \frac{5i}{n} - \frac{i^3}{n^3} + 2$

So we have,

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n((\frac{4i^2}{n^2} - \frac{5i}{n} - \frac{i^3}{n^3} + 2)\Delta x)$

The $\Delta x$ is constant, so we can take it out of the summation:

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n(\frac{4i^2}{n^2} - \frac{5i}{n} - \frac{i^3}{n^3} + 2)\Delta x$

Distribute the summation.

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(\sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{4i^2}{n^2} - \sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{5i}{n} - \sum_\limits{i=1}^n\frac{i^3}{n^3} + \sum_\limits{i=1}^n2)\Delta x$$

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(\frac{4}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{5}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{n^2(n+1)^2)}{4} + 2n)(\frac{1}{n})$$

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}(\frac{4}{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n} - \frac{5}{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2n} - \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{n^2(n+1)^2)}{4n} + \frac{2n}{n})$$

Evaluate the limit:

$$= \frac{8}{6} - \frac{5}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{1} = \frac{7}{12}$$

I wrote alot, so I might have made a mistake, but the final answer is correct so I probabbly did not

Answer (score 3):

I am getting $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(c_{i})\Delta x=\frac{5-12n+7n^2}{12n^2}$ so that the limit is $\frac{7}{12}$, which is the same as $\int_{-1}^{0}(x^2-x^3)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is [$\frac{7}{12}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-1+to+0+of+x%5E2-x%5E3).